# I don't understand this unexpected output, can anyone explain?

Tags: python

I expect the output as

```
[1,4,9,10,#]
```

but I am getting

```
[1,4,9,10]
```

Can anyone explain the reason as to why is that happening?

```
str = "adij"
mainstr = []
for i in range(0, len(str)):
    if 97 <= ord(str[i]) <= 107:
        mainstr.append(ord(str[i]) - 96)
    if ord(str[i]) > 107:
        mainstr.append(ord(str[i]) - 96)
        mainstr.append('#')
print mainstr
```

Comment: Do not _ever_ call your variable `str`. `str` is a string constructor. You may have messed up your Python interpreter already. And instead of cryptic `97 <= ord(str[i]) <= 107`, why not write `'a'<=str[i]<='k'`? You would immediately see what's wrong with  your expectations.

Comment: `ord('j')` = 106. So its less than 107.

Comment: In python you don't need a loop counter when iterating over characters in a string. Just do `for letter in str: mainstr.append(ord(letter))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `ord(str[i])` is never greater than `107`:

```
>>> ord("j") > 107
False
>>> ord("j")
106
```

therefore `mainstr.append("#")` is never even reached.

---

Other things you should fix:

- you should never call your variable `str`, `str` already means something (it's the [string class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str))
- In Python, you can compare strings directly. Use `"a" <= str[i] <= "k"`.
- You can just iterate over the characters in a string without a counter:

  ```
  for character in theString:
      if "a" <= character <= "k":
          # ...
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Character 107 is `'k'`. There are no characters in your string that follow `'k'` lexicographically, so the `if` statement that contains `mainstr.append('#')` is never triggered. The code that would add `'#'` to your list is never executed.